# UPDATE c# MySQL syn

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-update

I want to update a table with the time difference between two events. I've implemented this code:

```
TimeSpan ts = vett[0] - vett[1]; 
MySqlCommand cmdup = new MySqlCommand();

cmdup.CommandText = "UPDATE event_move SET diff_time=" + ts + "WHERE id_event_move=" + id_move[0];
cmdup.Connection = myConn;
myConn.Open();

cmdup.ExecuteNonQuery();

myConn.Close();
```

My Visual Studio 2010 indicates a syntax error at the line `cmdup.CommandText = ...`

Might you help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The source of the mistake is probably the missing space as [Giovanni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1728637/giovanni-guarino) says.
My tip would be to use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method.

```
cmdup.CommandText = String.Format("UPDATE event_move SET diff_time={0} WHERE id_event_move={1}", ts, id_move[0]);
```

Have you used this, you would spot the missing space immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Add space before WHERE condiction:

```
cmdup.CommandText = "UPDATE event_move SET diff_time=" + ts + " WHERE id_event_move=" + id_move[0];
```